# Model Selection when there is trade-off

Tags: machine-learning, classification, auc

[image]

This is one of my model variants. It achieves an AUC score of 0.73. Another one of my model variants achieves an AUC score of 0.7265. Below is the the confusion matrix -

[image]

Like many problems, the minority class(positive class) represents the customers I'd like to target. But having many false positives is going to cost me money.

Q - how to select a model and how such a massive difference in confusion matrix gives similar AUC scores?

Comment: These three blog posts by Vanderbilt’s Frank Harrell are essential reading for what you want to do. https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/  https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/ // When you say that the minority class is what is important to you but that false positives will cost you money, what do you mean? That makes it sound like both categories are important.

Comment: Minority class -  customers who are likely to respond to my ad. False positives - higher number means I spent money advertising to people who did not respond to my ad. That's why I mentioned it will cost me money.

Comment: How much do you think you can get from the people who do respond?